# How to scroll to see images on a website?

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I have this program that is meant to scroll down until it can find all of the pictures on the screen. This is my code:

```
def scrolluntil():
    allsat = False
    while allsat == False:
        pyautogui.scroll(-100)
        fan = locateCenterOnScreen("findaname.png")
        tl = locateCenterOnScreen("topleft.png")
        tr = locateCenterOnScreen("topright.png")
        if fan is not None:
            if tl is not None:
                if tr is not None:
                    allsat = True
```

It keeps scrolling down and doesn't stop even when the images are on the screen, the pictures are correct.

Comment: Is this your complete code? The function only control `allsat` and does not return something, and what is definition of `locateCenterOnScreen`?

Comment: locateCenterOnScreen is part of the pyautogui library, it finds the image on your screen. my function is meant to stop scrolling when all the images are found on the screen.

Comment: It's possible you need to use time.sleep between iterations. In my experience, locating an image with pyautogui takes several seconds, so I think if you added a time.sleep(10) after the `tr =` line, you may have more success. That way, you give the program enough time to search for the image before you continue scrolling.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set a flag for each of the things you want to find. The way the code is written now, `allsat=True` will only execute when all pictures are simultaneously in view.

This is a crude way to do it:

```
def scrolluntil():
    allsat = False
    fan    = False
    tl     = False
    tr     = False
    while allsat == False:
        pyautogui.scroll(-100)
        if fan == False:
            if locateCenterOnScreen("findaname.png") is not None:
                fan = True
        if tl == False:
            if locateCenterOnScreen("topleft.png") is not None:
                tl = True
        if tr == False:
            if locateCenterOnScreen("topright.png") is not None:
                tr = True
        if fan:
            if tl:
                if tr:
                    allsat = True
```

It's also worth noting that you may have to update your code to use a try...except block if you ever upgrade your version of `pyautogui`. From the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html?#the-locate-functions):

> NOTE: As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the
> provided image, they’ll raise ImageNotFoundException instead of
> returning None.